# Fetchxml How to fetch multiple attributes in a groupby fetch (aggregate)

Tags: group-by, dynamics-crm, aggregate, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have a fetchxml which worked fine until I added another attribute to the fetch.

```
 <attribute name="ey_b_closed_conversations" alias="isClosed" />
```

this is the line I added to the fetch, and now it doesn't work.
The following code is the complete fetchxml.

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0" aggregate="true" distinct="false"> 
  <entity name="ey_case_branch_callcenter_inquiry">
    <attribute name="ey_s_name" alias="count" aggregate="countcolumn" /> 
    <attribute name="ey_p_action" alias="id" groupby="true" /> 
    <attribute name="ey_b_closed_conversations" alias="isClosed" />  
      <filter>     
     <condition attribute="ey_case_sub_subjectid" operator="eq" value="{9E52CB8E-BEA6-E411-AFFF-0050568C0143}" />
    <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />       
    </filter>     
  </entity>   
</fetch>
```

Are there any limitations on the number of attributes I can fetch in an aggregated fetchxml?
How can I add my additional (non-aggregated) attribute to the fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any limitations on the number of attributes I can fetch in an aggregated fetchxml?

No.

> How can I add my additional (non-aggregated) attribute to the fetch?

You cannot.

---

You might have received this error: `An attribute can not be requested when an aggregate operation has been specified and its neither groupby nor aggregate.`

This is similar to SQL error: `Column 'xxxx' is invalid in the select list because it is not
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

This error is coming because the below line in your query does not have either `groupby` or `aggregate` property in the line.

```
<attribute name="ey_b_closed_conversations" alias="isClosed" />
```

Referring [this community post](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/215742/fetch-xml-groupby):

> This is because when you group by you can only include an attribute that you are not grouping-by as an aggregate ( E.g sum/min/max/count)

I tested the below and it worked:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0" aggregate="true" distinct="false" >
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="name" alias="count" aggregate="countcolumn" />
    <attribute name="telephone2" alias="phone" groupby="true" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" alias="mobile" aggregate="count" />
    <attribute name="accountnumber" alias="number" groupby="true" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT   count(name) AS count,
         count(telephone1) AS mobile,
         telephone2 AS phone,
         accountnumber AS number
FROM     account
WHERE    statecode = 0
GROUP BY telephone2, accountnumber
```

So either do this:

```
<attribute name="ey_b_closed_conversations" alias="isClosed" aggregate="count" />
```

or

```
<attribute name="ey_b_closed_conversations" alias="isClosed" groupby="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Got all the answers :)